# Bending a group of elements in SVG

Tags: svg

Is there a way to "bend" a `<g>` element and all of its children? An example would be the [old Windows logo](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/14/Windows_logo_-_2006.svg) where we have a group of four rectangles that is is bent along a wave:

```
<!-- How do I make this group "wavey"? -->
<g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
    <rect x="11" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
    <rect x="0" y="11" width="10" height="10" />
    <rect x="11" y="11" width="10" height="10" />
</g>
```

Edit: To make it even more clear: I'm looking for something like [`<textPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath), but for arbitrary elements or groups.

Comment: Possibly a displacement map filter, otherwise you're out of luck as SVG does not generally support non-affine transforms.

Comment: But displacement maps are a bitmap thing, right?

Comment: Seems to me you should just draw it wavy in the first place using paths.